converting a null literal to a non-nullable type
I cut my teeth in c++ many moons ago and it's all been system or console/excel programming/scripting for me from that point on. c# and Windows IDE (Studio and Code) are new to me so forgive if this is a very simple beginner question. I have googled but I've been unable to rectify this problem.
I'm trying to run a c# code in VSCode debugger but it's not compiling. Below is the line that's giving me a problem. I see this exact syntax given in many examples of similar use cases.
Console.Write("Please enter your name in the format of 'first last', for example: 'John Smith' or 'john smith' or 'john'.");
String users_name = Console.ReadLine();

The only "error" I see is this instance of Console.Readline() (which I understand can return a null value) that I'm setting to a String variable type (where none-nulls are not permitted). My understanding is I can "ignore" this in c# but I'm not certain how.
Is there a way I can assign something that 'could' return a null value to a non-nullable data type? an exception?
I've tried setting the "users_name" variable to some user input from console. It's casting a problem that a none-null data type can't be set to a method that could return a null value. I expect to accept some user input form console and use it throughout the program.

You can just make it nullable
string? users_name = Console.ReadLine();

See: learn.microsoft.com on that warning (not error).

That would be #nullable disable for the warning not to be issued in the first place. Or disable it in the project file *.csproj.

String users_name = Console.ReadLine() ?? ""; if we want to treat null as an empty string.

If you want to assign a possibly null value to a non-nullable variable, you need to use a null-checking operator, such as ??. This returns the value to the right of the operator if the value to the left is null, otherwise the value to the left, and can also be used to throw an exception.
For example:
Console.Write("Please enter your name in the format of 'first last', for example: 'John Smith' or 'john smith' or 'john'.");
var input = Console.ReadLine();
var defaultInputToEmptyStringifNull = input ?? string.Empty;
var throwExceptionIfNull = input ?? throw new Exception("Null value is not allowed");

Edit - I will add, that your original line of String users_name = Console.ReadLine(); should actually compile unless you have the CS8600 warning level set to produce a compilation error (I don't know about VSCode, perhaps this defaults to this setting?). A more permissive setting would compile this, but throw a NullReferenceException at run-time if receiving a null value.

You could make your variable nullable:
string? users_name = Console.ReadLine();

Or if you want to use a non-nullable value, supply a default non-null value if null is returned from ReadLine():
string users_name = Console.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;

(Or any other default value you want to use.)
